# converting youtube audio into .mp3 with ffmpeg: ERROR: audio conversion failed: encoder: Lavc58.91.100 libmp3lame

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm getting the error below when trying to play audio through my discord bot, I have all the dependencies installed and afaik ffmpeg is working.

```
The bot has connected to General

Downloading audio now

[youtube] X9zaArvqZXM: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Wombo Combo _ Shotgun Willy ft. Lil Kapow _ Lyrics-X9zaArvqZXM.webm
[download] 100% of 2.87MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Destination: Wombo Combo _ Shotgun Willy ft. Lil Kapow _ Lyrics-X9zaArvqZXM.mp3
ERROR: audio conversion failed:       encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libmp3lame
```

my ydl_opts are below

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '128',
    }],
}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: you might have a disconnect between your bot and the ffmpeg executable. see if your bot can execute simple ffmpeg actions to test the link between them

Comment: how would I go about making sure my bot can use the executable?

Comment: You can check [how-to-use-ffmpeg-on-python](https://yanwei-liu.medium.com/how-to-use-ffmpeg-on-python-2ba3fa360ba7) out.

Comment: ye everything's working